# How to create a loop to Copy and Paste Data from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a macro that is supposed to select a row of stress data from one worksheet and paste it in a table on another worksheet, then select the corresponding strain data (found in a row underneath) and paste it in the same table.

The initial starting locations for the data from sheet *ImportTXT* will always be the same (Row 51), and the table in sheet *ExtractData* should always be in the same location as well, so pasting will always start in "D8:I8". I would like to write it so that it runs until there are blank cells (so until the end, no matter how many rows of stress and strain there are) since the length of data can range (the cell reference (i.e "until row 122" will not exist; will not always be fixed amount).

The repetitive code that I have so far:

```
Sub CutCopyPasteData()
    Worksheets("ImportTXT").Range("B51:G51").Copy Worksheets("ExtractData").Range("D8:I8")
    Worksheets("ImportTXT").Range("D52:G52").Copy Worksheets("ExtractData").Range("J8:M8")

    Worksheets("ImportTXT").Range("B53:G53").Copy Worksheets("ExtractData").Range("D9:I9")
    Worksheets("ImportTXT").Range("D54:G54").Copy Worksheets("ExtractData").Range("J9:M9")

    Worksheets("ImportTXT").Range("B55:G55").Copy Worksheets("ExtractData").Range("D10:I10")
    Worksheets("ImportTXT").Range("D56:G56").Copy Worksheets("ExtractData").Range("J10:M10")
End Sub
```

These are just for the first three rows, however as you can see "Bx:Gx" and "Dx:Gx" increases by 2 and "Dx:Ix" as well as "Jx:Mx" increases by 1.

An image of the data in the organized form:

[An image of the table output with first three rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRedJ.png)

If there is any for loop or do until loop that can dynamically update the cell references and copy pate all the data then that would be my goal. Thx.

Comment: The response from @Tim Williams works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub CutCopyPasteData()

    Dim rngImp1 As Range, rngImp2 As Range, rngDest As Range

    Set rngImp1 = Worksheets("ImportTXT").Range("B51:G51")
    Set rngImp2 = Worksheets("ImportTXT").Range("D52:G52")
    Set rngDest = Worksheets("ExtractData").Rows(8)

    Do While Application.CountA(rngImp1) > 0

        rngImp1.Copy rngDest.Range("D1") 'the 1 is relative to the row...
        rngImp2.Copy rngDest.Range("J1")

        Set rngImp1 = rngImp1.Offset(2, 0) 'move down 2 rows
        Set rngImp2 = rngImp2.Offset(2, 0)
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0) 'move down 1 row
    Loop
End Sub
```